# can not add luaeclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lua, coronasdk

I can not add lua plugins into eclipse using this links:

"http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/update-site/site.xml"

when i enter this link into "help"->"install new software"
it shows "could not find"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.  Try using this update site instead:

```
http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/update-site/
```

More likely though, you are behind a firewall.  If so, you need to set your proxies in Preferences -> General -> Network preferences.